# capistrano deployment fails with error not able to create /u/apps/...

Tags: capistrano

After having had no problems in a multi environment deployment, all in a sudden, I got this error:

```
** [server.com :: out] fatal: could not create leading directories of '/u/apps/application/shared/cached-copy': Permission denied
```

I am not sure why this happens. What I am wondering is the directory mentioned in the message:

```
/u/apps/
```

Ther is no such directory and I do not have it written in the deployment tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some information about the correct deployment path's have been lost. So running these commands have fixed the issue:

```
cap preview deploy:setup
cap production deploy:setup
```

Answer (score 3):

`/u/apps` is the default prefix used when `:deploy_to` is not set.  Commonly only the root user has privileges to create the `/u` directory, so errors like this pop up with the default prefix and when Capistrano is not run as root.